# doctrine DQL comments inside query string

Tags: doctrine, dql

I just wondering if doctrine has support for comments inside DQL query (like for example mysql does)

In mysql I can:

```
    $sql = "
        SELECT t.id
        FROM ticket_table t
        WHERE
            t.eventId = 123
            -- AND t.status = 5
           /* OR add comment like this and the query is valid */
    ";
```

In dql nothing of aforementioned is valid

```
    $dql = "
        SELECT t.id
        FROM ".Ticket::class." t
        WHERE
            t.eventId = 123
            AND t.status = 5
            -- can't do this
            /* can't do this either */
    ";
```

Comment: DQL != SQL , DQL is parsed by ORM and result in raw SQL query. I don't see any strong reason to support `--` in DQL

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/4168